# Visiting every instruction (bytecode) using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I have a working profiler that relies on the BCEL library but since the later is not supported anymore by JDK1.7 or later, I am trying to replicate using the ASM library. Is there a way to visit every instruction of a method using the MethodVisitor class?
I found a way using ClassNode, MethodNode and InsnList, but I am interested to see if it can be implemented using the Visitor framework. The below code shows what I want to do

```
// main function
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path_to_classfile.class");
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(in);
ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
reader.accept(classNode,0);

List<MethodNode> methods = classNode.methods;
for(MethodNode m: methods){
    System.out.println("Method name: " + m.name);
    InsnList m_instructionList= m.instructions;
    for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m_instructionList.size(); m_i++){
       AbstractInsnNode instruction = m_instructionList.get(m_i);
       if(instruction.getOpcode() == Opcodes.ISTORE){
            // insert bytecode to call a profiler method
        }else if(instruction.getOpcode() == Opcodes.FSTORE){
            // insert call to a a profiler method
        }
        else if...
    }
}
// Write to a .class file
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have posted is not visiting, it is iterating. If you understand the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), you should be able to do visit or to post your actual visitor code you’re struggling with. If not, it’s outside the scope of Stackoverflow…

Comment: And [the tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) is quiet comprehensive…

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to do the same thing (i.e., **visit every instruction of a method**) using the visitor classes... If I had a visitor code I would have posted it...

Comment: Follow the tutorial, create a subclass of `MethodVisitor`, override every `visit…` method. Which part do you have problems with?